# Having trouble showing GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Here is my code

```
public void gridshow() {
        sc.Open();
        //int custtid ;
        //custtid = (int)cidshow.SelectedItem;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Cust_id , Cust_name from Cust_master where Cust_id = '" + cidshow.SelectedItem + "'", sc);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,"Cust_master");
        custshow.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        sc.Close();

    }
```

Error raised is

```
(Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cidshow.SelectedItem` is a `DataRowView`, you can't use it the way you are.

Try accessing just the value you need, using something like:

```
... Convert.ToString(((DataRowView)cidshow.SelectedItem)["customerId"]) ...
```

Also, look into parameterizing your queries. It's safer, and it makes your query easier to read and maintain in the future.

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "select Cust_id , Cust_name from Cust_master where Cust_id = @custId", sc);

da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custId", yourCustomerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `cidshow` is a databound combobox, `SelectedItem` returns a DataRowView. You will have to extract your ID field from that object

```
 ....
 int custtid ;
 DateGridView custdgv = cidshow.SelectedItem;
 int custtid = Convert.ToInt(custdgv["customerId"]);
 ....
```